# Realtime blit bitmap in GTK/cairo

Tags: gtk, real-time, render, blit

In Windows, I can blit a bitmap to a DC picked up by GetDC at any time without calling InvalidateRect issuing a WM_PAINT message. How do I port this behavior to GTK/cairo?

In a background thread, I want to

1. Scale a given bitmap to "best-fit" inside a window (Need to know the width and height of  in pixels)
2. Blit the scaled image to the screen

It should not be done through the expose event (the render loop is fast so the window will be drawn in time anyway). Full logic is

1. Create a window
2. Get context of the window
3. Start message loop
4. User presses a "Start" button
5. A new program thread is started that checks for a stop flag. If it is false, it issues commands that update the contents of the window regularly *without* user interaction. Meanwhile, the message loop checks for user input.
6. When user presses a "Stop" button the stop flag raises causing the rendering thread to exit

When rendering thread is not running, the expose event should call the same code as the render thread.

I have tried to catch the cairo_t* cairo_obj after creating a GtkDrawingArea (I get one)

the animation thread then calls image draw repeatedly issuing

```
cairo_set_source_rgb(cairo_obj, 1, 0, 0);
cairo_select_font_face(cairo_obj, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
    CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
cairo_set_font_size(cairo_obj, 40.0);

cairo_move_to(cairo_obj, 10.0, 50.0);
cairo_show_text(cairo_obj, "Disziplin ist Macht.");
```

This works when doing event passing but not otherwise. Are there any other calls that has to be done at the end of the drawing code swapping buffers?

If this cannot be done with GTK/cairo, are there any other toolkit that lets me do this? Is it possible under X at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. All drawing has to be done through the expose event in the end. Are you trying to figure out how to render the bitmap to a backing store and blit that to the screen during the expose event?

Comment: @ptomato Then it cannot be done in GTK. Can it be done in another toolkit (or raw X)

Comment: Before concluding that it cannot be done, please try to explain more clearly in your question why you don't want to use the expose event.

Comment: @ptomato If I were to use expose event, the rendering has to run in the same thread as the gui input since the message queue is not thread safe and threading support is deprecated. Running the rendering in the gui thread would block the gui until a frame is posted for display.

Comment: Threading support is definitely not deprecated. Only directly accessing the GDK lock is deprecated (see: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2012-September/msg00013.html) Do the rendering in a separate thread, to a backing store, and blit that to the screen in the expose event, with appropriate use of semaphores. All drawing has to be done through the expose event, whether you are using multiple threads or not.